# Cant find webjob once deployed to Azure Web App?

Tags: powershell, azure-webjobs

I have a webapp in Azure , TestApp in RG TestRG . I have created a zip for deployment and use the following powershell script

```
az webapp deployment source config-zip -n "TestApp" -g "TestRG" --src "c:\test\deployfile.zip"
```

It gives the warning

"az : Getting scm site credentials for zip deployment"

Then it says the following:

```
Starting zip deployment. This operation can take a while to complete ...
Deployment endpoint responded with status code 202
```

But after that i get a json response that it succeeded under provisioningState field.

When i navigate to the App service in Azure under Setings -WebJobs I dont see that web Job ?

Is there an issue with the powershell script ?

Comment: Could you please check for directory structure?  To deploy a webjob, create a zip file with content structure as it will be deflated to d:\home\site\wwwroot as is - for instance, the top level folder when you open a zip file should be App_Data folder. Then, simply use zipdeploy to deploy the zip. 
See- This document link https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs 

Also check this blog link: https://mariankostal.com/2020/07/17/deploy-azure-webjob-using-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [SnehaAgrawal-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10893879/snehaagrawal-msft). Posting your suggestions as answer to help other community members.

To deploy a web Job could you please check your directory structure. Try to create a zip file which will be deflated to **d:\home\site\wwwroot** where you will be finding a folder called App_Data once you open the ZIP file.

Below code will help yoou in deploying the Azure Web Job.

```
param
(
    [string] $buildOutput = $(throw "Directory with build output is required"),
    [string] $resourceGroupName = $(throw "Resource group name is required"),
    [string] $webAppName = $(throw "Web app name is required"),
    [string] $webJobName = $(throw "Web job name is required"),
    [string] $webJobType = "triggered"
)
 
$currentDir = (Get-Item .).FullName
$tempDir = "$currentDir\Temp"
$webJobDir = "$tempDir\App_Data\jobs\$webJobType\$webJobName"
 
New-Item $webJobDir -ItemType Directory
Copy-Item "$buildOutput\*" -Destination $webJobDir -Recurse
Compress-Archive -Path "$tempDir\*" -DestinationPath ".\$webJobName.zip"
Remove-Item $tempDir -Recurse -Force
 
az webapp deployment source config-zip -g $resourceGroupName -n $webAppName --src "$webJobName.zip"
```

Could you please check the [Deploy Azure Web Job](https://mariankostal.com/2020/07/17/deploy-azure-webjob-using-powershell/) documentation for further information. Also check the related links in that documentation.