# Unable to create new webjob in an existing webapp through Terraform or AZ CLI

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-webjobs, azure-cli, azure-webapps

I have a problem statement which are defined in below steps.

1. Download a .ps1 file from a container
2. Create a temporary directory
3. Convert it into a zip file
4. Create a new continuous or triggered webjob in an existing webapp by deploying this zip file.
5. Delete the temporary directory.

I am unable to execute step 4 as there are no commands available in either Terraform or azure cli to create a new webjob. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to create new webjob in an existing webapp through Terraform or AZ CLI

I have followed [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73506527/how-do-i-add-a-webjob-to-my-aspnet-appservice-using-only-the-cli) and [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-deploy) and have reproduced in my environment as below:

```
 az webapp deploy --name "name of web app service" -g "name of resource grp" --src-path "C:\Users\source\repos\ConsoleApp@.zip"  --type static --target-path /home/site/wwwroot/emojob
```

[image]

In Portal in Kudu console:

[image]

For further you can refer [reference1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71312850/azure-cli-az-webapp-deployment-source-config-zip-is-deleting-anothers-webjob) and [reference2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69127218/cant-find-webjob-once-deployed-to-azure-web-app).

If you want to start, stop, remove or list the webjobs you can use `az webapp webjob` [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/webjob?view=azure-cli-latest).

Comment: Is there any way to deploy it through ARM template?

Comment: You need to open a new question for that!